# Programmatically converted SSRS report to Pdf priting issue

Tags: c#, reporting-services

we have an SSRS report which is working fine.Recently we made some changes so that the SSRS will load directly in pdf. But now the issue is with printing. When print is taken the alignment are changed.we are using A5 page size.

Code used to convert SSRS to PDF

```
     ReportingService rs = new ReportingService();
---
----
    result = rs.Render(reportPath, "PDF", historyID, devInfo, parameters, credentials,showHideToggle, out encoding, out mimeType, out reportHistoryParameters, out warnings,
                out streamIDs);
```

Setting done while printing
 1.checked choose paper source by PDF page size
 2. Page size set as Fit.
Now actually we are stuck with that. please provide a solution..

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check the properties of your report. (Right mouse click, just outside the body of the report). Your width and height should not go out of your A5 page size. Picture are for refrence.
[image]

Now you should also check  width of the report to the landscape size of your A5 paper

[image]

Comment: thanks for the replay.All the setting  are already done and printing is working perfectly before the pdf updation.

Comment: @SandeepPPillai If the answer helped you, please mark it as solved. Thanks.

Comment: all those settings are already done. i think the issue is something different